# iOS Mobile App Testing on Windows

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile, ios, seetest

I am taking my first dive into testing a mobile app.  It will be available to iOS and Android.  I've been searching for a way to test and automate iOS without having an actual iPhone or any other Mac device.  We run Windows here at the office.  I was looking to use iPhone emulators but it doesn't seem possible.  I saw Appium Studio/SeeTest but it seems even that requires iTunes and a real device.  I know you can set up a Mac vm on a Windows machine but are there any other ways to test iPhone without having to do this?

Comment: May be you can try this way : http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox

Comment: Is there any update regarding these or still you are unable to do iOS testing in windows! @JohnP15

Comment: @NawshadRehanRasha sadly no biggers changes here yet.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there are no known emulators for the iPhone on Windows, and it's unlikely there ever will be one I'd be willing to consider testing an important program in.  Apple is very tied to using the Mac toolchain for development, and unless they release Xcode for Windows, that's not going to change.  In order to test iPhone software, you either need to have Apple devices yourself (note that running Mac OS on non-Apple hardware is a violation of the Mac software license), or enlist the services of something like https://www.browserstack.com/app-live, https://appexperience.sigos.com, or https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud.

Comment: I did find browserstack applive in my research and plan on using it but would I be able to automate tests through it?

Comment: @JohnP15 Yes, you can. More here:
https://www.browserstack.com/automate/physical-mobile-devices

Answer (score 0):

There are few labs right now that you can choose from if you don't have access to real iOS devices.

Few of them:

- TestDroid
- Sauce labs
- Perfecto Mobile
- Kobiton
- Amazon AWS Device farm
- Google FireBase
- Xamarin Test Cloud
- Experitest
- pCloudy
- BrowserStack